# Как автоматически менять высоту одного блока в зависимости от высоты другого

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. В JS ничего не понимаю. Но возникла необходимость менять высоту одного блока на странице в зависимости от высоты другого блока на этой же страницы. Я так понимаю это можно сделать только с помощью JS. Помогите кто может.

Есть `<div id="1">` и `<div id="2">`. У первого высота (height) меняется в зависимости от действий пользователя, а у второго в этот момент нижний отступ (margin-bottom) должен меняться и быть равным высоте первого.

То есть если у первого высота 50px, то у второго нижний отступ 50px.
Если у первого высота стала 100px, то и у второго отступ должен поменяться на 100px.

Код примерно такой:

```html
    <div id="1" style="height:auto;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;min-height:50px;">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea> 
    </div>

    <div id="2" style="margin-bottom:50px;"> Основной контент страницы </div>
```

Всё это надо, чтобы фиксированный блок не перекрывал основной контент.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Это делается не обязательно через JS, зависит от «У первого высота (height) меняется в зависимости от действий пользователя» — нужен пример разметки (и каким образом высота 1-го блока меняется)

Comment: Пример добавил. Высота первого блока меняется потому что внутри этого блока текстовый input. И когда много текста этот input увеличивается в высоте. Соответственно, чтобы он не перекрывал основной контент страницы, надо делать нижний отступ больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот + чтоб textarea подстраивала свою высоту под вводимый текст.
Потому как если она не будет менять свою высоту, то и нечего следить за margin-ом ))

```
<body>
        <div
            id="1"
            style="
                height: auto;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 50px;
                border: 2px solid green;
            "
        >
            <textarea id="myTextarea" cols="50" style="height: 50px"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div
            id="2"
            style="margin-bottom: 50px; font-size: 2em; border: 2px solid red"
        >
            Основной контент страницы <br />
        </div>

        <script>
            const myTextarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
            const myId1 = document.getElementById("1");
            const myId2 = document.getElementById("2");

            // прокрутить окно в самый низ 1 раз
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

            // обработчик события в textarea
            myTextarea.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
                // чтобы textarea менялась по высоте вслед за вводимым текстом
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                if (this.scrollTop > 0) {
                    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px";
                    myId1.style.height = this.style.height;
                }

                // правим высоту 2-го блока
                myId2.style.marginBottom = myId1.style.height;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то так?

```js
let x = 20
document.querySelector(".btn").onclick = ()=>{
  document.querySelector(".first").style.height = x +"px"
  x+=10
  document.querySelector(".second").style.marginBottom = x-10 +"px"
}
```

```css
body{
display:flex;
align-items:flex-end;
}
.first{
width:70px;
height:20px;
background-color:gold;
}
.second{
width:70px;
height:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background-color:silver;
}
```

```html
<div class = "first"></div>
<div class = "second"></div>
<button class = "btn">+</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня получается в первом div вставлен input и когда пользователь пишет сообщение высота первого div меняется в зависимости от высоты input. И вот, чтобы первый div не перекрывал контент страницы надо делать снизу отступ соразмерный высоте первого div'a.